# keep network activity indicator spinning

Tags: ios

I found that sometimes you may be doing something in your iPhone application that requires the user to wait while it completes. Often this is a network related activity, but in other cases it may not be. In my case I was parsing the response from a network connection and wanted the network activity indicator to keep spinning even though it had already downloaded the content.

below is what i'm doing:

applicationDelegate.m :

```
- (void)setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:(BOOL)setVisible
{
    static NSInteger NumberOfCallsToSetVisible = 0;
    if (setVisible) 
        NumberOfCallsToSetVisible++;
    else 
        NumberOfCallsToSetVisible--;

    // Display the indicator as long as our static counter is > 0.
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:(NumberOfCallsToSetVisible > 0)];
}
```

otherView.m:

```
dispatch_queue_t dataLoadingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("synchronise", NULL);
    dispatch_async(dataLoadingQueue,
                   ^{
                       [appDelegate setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];
                       [[DataLoader instance]LoadDataForGrewal];
                       [[FieldConsultantViewModelManager instance] resetCache];  
                       [[DailyFieldConsultantViewModelManager instance] clearCache];
                       [appDelegate loadMainViews];
                       [[DataLoader instance]LoadDataForOtherEntities]; 
                       [appDelegate setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];
                   });    
 dispatch_release(dataLoadingQueue);
```

as u can see above, i'm trying to keep the network indicator while updating the data into the database but it does not work , any clue / suggestions ?

Thanks
**EDIT :**

```
dispatch_queue_t dataLoadingQueue = dispatch_queue_create("synchronise", NULL);
    dispatch_async(dataLoadingQueue,
                   ^{
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES]; });
                       [[DataLoader instance]LoadDataForGrewal];
                       [[FieldConsultantViewModelManager instance] resetCache];  
                       [[DailyFieldConsultantViewModelManager instance] clearCache];
                       [appDelegate loadMainViews];
                       [[DataLoader instance]LoadDataForOtherEntities]; 
                       dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{ [self setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO]; });
                   });    
 dispatch_release(dataLoadingQueue);
```

it does not work i'm not sure why because i'm newbie in ios

Comment: Are those methods between the two calls to setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible asynchronous or synchronous in nature?

Comment: Thanks, has been fixed. there was async call that gets the control to the activity indicator between the two calls to setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible

Answer (score 2):

try to dispatch your `setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:` call on main queue, because UIApplication is in UIKit and UIKit is not thread-safe.

Comment: you meant like this :dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),
                                      ^{
                                          [self setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:NO];               
                                      });

Comment: exactly like this, for both calls. and maybe for your loadMainView call, i don't know what this method is doing but based on its name i assume it's doing some UIKit's stuff.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone looking for a complete solution, this is what I use (in **Swift**). It delays a short duration when stopping the network indicator. This will prevent the indicator from flickering if you have a lot of serial network request.

```
private var networkActivityCount = 0

func updateNetworkActivityCount(increaseNumber increase:Bool)
{
    let appendingCount = increase ? 1 : -1
    networkActivityCount += appendingCount
    let delayInSeconds = increase ? 0.0 : 0.7
    perform({ () -> () in
        let application = UIApplication.sharedApplication()
        let shouldBeVisible = self.networkActivityCount > 0
        if application.networkActivityIndicatorVisible != shouldBeVisible {
            application.networkActivityIndicatorVisible = shouldBeVisible
        }
    }, afterDelay: delayInSeconds)
}
```

Where `perform:afterDelay` is defined as

```
public func perform(block: ()->(), afterDelay:Double) {
    let dispatchTime: dispatch_time_t = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, Int64(afterDelay * Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)))
    dispatch_after(dispatchTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
         block()
    })
}
```

Just call `updateNetworkActivityCount(increaseNumber: true)` before your request and the same with `false` in your request callback. I.e:

```
updateNetworkActivityCount(increaseNumber: true)
let task = urlSession.dataTaskWithRequest(request) { data, response, error in
    self.updateNetworkActivityCount(increaseNumber: false)
    ...
```